# Is this the right statistic test to use?

Tags: chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics

I have 2 variables:

1. Age group
2. Yes/No response to a question of whether participants ate breakfast that morning.

The sample size is 900.

I want to find out whether a certain age group is more likely to have had breakfast than another age group.

Am I right in thinking I would calculate the odds ratio and then Chi square test between the two variables? How do I work out which age group is most likely to have had breakfast?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do a logistic regression with "Breakfast eating" as the dependent variable and age group as the independent variable. If you are only interested in one particular age group, you can make it the reference category and will then be able to compare every other age group to it.

Comment: I agree with Peter Flom's answer.  To carry it out, you will need to organise your data into two columns (long form), code Yes/No breakfast as 1/0, and code Age into categories eg. 13 to 15 = 1;  16 to 18=2;  etc.